# Share a VPN connection with non-VPN capable devices

Tags: networking, vpn, lan

I have a VPN connection through Cisco AnyConnect that I'd like to make available to other devices on my LAN. These devices (tablets, cellphones, media players ...) can't handle or don't implement the VPN software required to access the remote point.

My setup is the typical LAN with a router handling DHCP internally and connecting to the outside world. I wanted to have one computer on the LAN that would be in charge of receiving the traffic from these VPNless devices on the LAN and route it through the computer's VPN connection, essentially making the VPN available to those devices.

Not all devices need to connect through the VPN so they would still connect as usual on the LAN.

Is this possible and how can I do this? Does it require separate LANs for the devices that use the VPN and those that don't?

Comment: Can you add some more details of your current VPN setup.

Comment: It's a Cisco AnyConnect provided by my university.

Comment: what kind of router are you using? VLAN might be a solution for you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess that you are trying to share an Internet location that is available via VPN.

If WiFi is an option, than the following free products can share the connection from the VPN-connected computer :

[Connectify](http://www.connectify.me/)
[Virtual Router](http://virtualrouter.codeplex.com/)

Please note that if 
the VPN server dictates a compulsory tunnel, then logging-on to it will cut off any other access to any external computer, including the LAN, so no sharing is possible.

Answer (score 1):

I agree with you harrymc, if you want to get access in the internet for your wireless gadgets, then you should be using wifi, but there are also some case that you can use VPN in connecting, you just need to convert your laptop (if you want to connect your laptop)  into Wifi VPN router. If you want a vpn server that will give you the best access, try to connect with this top five VPN:

- IPVanish
- PureVPN
- ExpressVPN
- HideMyAss
- PrivateInternetAccess